# Remove Footer from Lightning Action Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience

I added a new custom action with a visualforce page as the content. But it still has the cancel and save buttons at the bottom of the action. I'm trying to remove these as they do not make sense in my action. Here is the style I've tried adding to hide them:

```
.slds .modal-footer .slds-modal__footer {
    display:none;
}
.modal-footer .slds-modal__footer {
    display:none;
}
.slds-modal__footer {
    display:none;
}
.modal-footer {
    display:none;
}
```

Can I hide the footer or override the values in buttons?

Comment: I am a little confused with your title and description: is your quick action a visualforce page or a lightning component?

Comment: It's a lightning action, so you can add a button next to new, edit, delete, etc.. in lightning experience. When you click that button a modal pops up. You can create custom ones that use visualforce and that's what I'm trying to do. But since I'm making a custom visualforce page within the modal popup I don't need the cancel and save buttons that come standard on the modal popup. So I'm trying to hide those or at least change the value of those to something other than save and cancel

Comment: Try setting showHeader and showQuickActionVfHeader to false: <apex:page showHeader="false" showQuickActionVfHeader="false"></apex:page>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to impact the styles of the action modal from your Visualforce because Salesforce uses an `iframe` to place your content. This is a security measure and is explicitly meant to stop you from stepping outside the bounds of your page (even if you are trying to do something harmless like hide the modal buttons).

If you are willing to convert your page to a lightning component take a look at the `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader` interface which will allow you to make a component quick action without the header or controls.

Additional details can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_interfaces.htm).

Just to give a preview this is what an example looks like:

[image]

Comment: that's interesting, I wonder what is the point of having a save button on  visualforce modal? The cancel and save button are there but the save is always greyed out when you have a visualforce page there as far as I can tell

Comment: Is your visualforce page leveraging a `standardcontroller`?

Comment: No just a custom controller

Comment: I have not tested this but it may be the case that those buttons will become enabled if you are using a `standardcontroller` because they can bind to the standard controller actions.

Answer (score 4):

To hide the header, add **showQuickActionVfHeader=“false”** to the apex:page>

Document Link : [Hide the Action Header for Visualforce Custom Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_actions_vf_pages_remove_pub_header.htm&type=0)

Example :

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="AccountController" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" >
```

Thanks

Anup

Comment: This looks like correct answer.This helps with footer removal as well in Vf quick action

Answer (score 1):

The approach that I have used to make my own 'modal' is to use`force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader` and after that, with a blank layout added 2 divs as follows 
`<div class="slds-has-divider--top slds-m-vertical--large slds-grid--pull-padded-medium"></div>` in order to divide my blank layout in 3 blocks which I can use as a header, body and footer. So, finally it looks something like this.

[image]

Comment: While this answer is a good start it would be more helpful it you posted your code or markup behind it.

Comment: This answer actually belongs someplace else, a good workaround - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160535/add-button-to-the-footer-of-a-lightning-quick-action-component/164334

Comment: @raul:Can you post your code for the above budgetary design screen shot. With that div , I am actually getting two scroolbar