# Add button to the footer of a Lightning Quick Action component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, quickaction

Can you add an additional footer button next to Cancel for a Lightning Quick Action?

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <ui:button label="Save Button" />
</aura:component>
```

I'm aware that I can use `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader` and customize the whole design. Just wondering in the Lightning System provides a built in way of doing this.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
    <ui:button label="Save Button" />
    <ui:button label="Cancel Button" />
</aura:component>
```

[image: Lightning Quick Action Modal]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. I would like to be able to do it to, at least customize the behavior of the "Save" button, but unfortunately it's not possible.

As you said, you need either to put the button inside your component with `force:lightningQuickAction`, or recreate everything in a component with `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader`. Solution 1 is easier but not good looking and not consistent with the standard UI, but solution 2 needs more work.

You can use Salesforce Lightning Design System [modal](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/#flavor-base-default) as a starting point for solution 2, but bear in mind that the look & feel is different in Salesforce1, if you use it.

Also, you can create a [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) for that and post the link here, I would be the first one to vote for it.

Last point, if you have access to the Partner Community, I asked the question [here](https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009NQx&fId=0D53A00002tRAJ1) so I guess you can add your own comment to the thread to show the PMs I'm not the only one interested.

Comment: Would you mind sharing you code to get it done using force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix it myself. This solution override the dialog box height which you mentioned while creating custom action on an object. I hope this will help someone needed.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" controller="MilindTest">     
<style>
    .cuf-content {
    padding: 0 0rem !important;
    }
    .slds-p-around--medium {
    padding: 0rem !important;
    }
    .slds-modal__content {
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    height: unset !important;
    max-height: unset !important;
    }        
</style>

<div class="slds-col modal-header slds-modal__header">
    <h2 class="title slds-text-heading--medium">Milind Test</h2>
</div>
<div class="slds-col modal-body scrollable slds-p-around--medium" style="height: 200px; max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto !important">
    <div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col modal-footer slds-modal__footer">        
    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{! c.cancelClick }" />      
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{! c.saveClick }" />
</div>
```

</aura:component>

Comment: No feasible anymore with api >= 42.0. CSS styles within cmps are disallowed by now.

Comment: You can add style directly with api >= 42.0 by using <aura:html tag="style">your_css_contents</aura:html>!

Comment: I did this the way Jon mentions successfully.  Still annoying, as we move forward with lwc it seems there are lots of little problems similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
    <footer>
        <div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer attach-to-bottom">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">Cancel</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save</button>
        </div>
    </footer>
</aura:component>

CSS
.THIS .attach-to-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate to this:
[how to access the save button in a modal when implementing the force:lightningQuickAction](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151000/how-to-access-the-save-button-in-a-modal-when-implementing-the-forcelightningqu)

And an idea was created here: 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNRIQA2

Answer (score 0):

I basically use sticky css on the footer making sure the footer element is with the modal content, which is the complete modal content for a force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader

With this, the footer will always be sticky to the bottom of the body and the all the content in Body1 div will be scrollable and will scroll under the footer.

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
    <aura:html tag="style">
        .slds-modal__container{
        max-width: 70rem !important;
        width:70% !important;
        }
        .slds-modal__container .cuf-content {
        padding:0 !important;
        }
        .slds-modal__container .slds-p-around--medium {
        padding: 0rem !important;
        }
        .slds-modal__content {
        height: unset !important;
        max-height: unset !important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: unset !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: unset !important;
        }
    </aura:html>
    <div style="height:40rem;max-height:40rem>
       <div>Body1</div>
       <footer class="slds-modal__footer">FooterBody</footer>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Custom CSS for Footer:

```
footer {
    position:stikcy,
    bottom:0,
    z-index:2
}
```