# Lightning component - Put button in footer

Tags: lightning, button

Below you can see a part of a custom mailing component that I've written.
To, in the end, send the actual mail, the "Mail" button needs to be pressed.

Visually, it would be much better if the button would appear left of the "Cancel" button in the footer of the form.

How am I able to do this?

You can find the code of the component and a screenshot below.

Already a big thanks!

[image]

```
<aura:component implements=....>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="mails" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="body" type="String" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="subject" type="String" default="" />
    <div>

        ...
        Keep in mind these suggestions will be based on the current available data.<br></br>
        <lightning:button label="Mail" onclick="{!c.mail}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Does your component implements `force:lightningQuickAction` ?

Comment: Yes it does, but how is this then used by the button defined in the cmp?

Comment: Have a look at this post , they seem to have the same problem https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160535/add-button-to-the-footer-of-a-lightning-quick-action-component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot modify the standard footer. As a workaround, you can implement **force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader** instead of **force:lightningQuickAction** in your component. This will remove the standard footer including the cancel button .

Then you can customize both Mail and Cancel Button as per your requirement using slds.

Comment: Too bad we cannot alter the standard footer, I thought I looked over some options, clearly not :(    Thanks for the response!

Comment: Added `force:lightningQuickActionWithout Header` instead of `force:lightningQuickAction` but how Can close the Pop-up on pressing the Custom cancel button. will `force:closeQuickAction` close the pop-up